# How to bind folder path in to vuetify v-text-box?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuetify.js

How do I set or bind a folder path into a v-text-box filed? I don't want to select all the files inside the directory I only needed the folder path.

I tried this
`<input type="file" webkitdirectory directory multiple>`
but this is selecting all the files from the directory not returning the directory path?

Please help with this.

Comment: Your question is bit mysterious

Comment: ```<v-text-field
            label="Incoming Folder"
            outlined
            prepend-inner-icon="mdi-folder-download"
            :rules="folderRules"
            :value="incommingFolder"
          ></v-text-field>``` I need to  browse only folder path in to this field.

Answer (score 0):

That's not what the webkitdirectory/directory attributes are for; they will load all the files inside that folder. Either way, there's no way to adchieve what you want cause browsers JS have no access to the File System.